# How to plot magnetic field lines "MANUALLY"?

Tags: magnetic-fields

We all know that "magnet" are consist of "dipoles".

So we can imagine each dipole is a "miniature magnet".

So if I want to "plot" the gradient vector of a magnet on certain point.

Am I correct to assume that it's the "sum vector" (red vector) of "all dipoles (black dots) acting on that point (green vectors)"!?

[image]

Comment: Wherever the fields line intersect, take the vector sum to draw the actual field lines. But that will happen everywhere so you will not be able to get an accurate field ***manually***.

Comment: So my "assumption" is correct!?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you will have to take the vector sum at every point.